# .NET CORE MVC ViewComponent xUnit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have started using xUnit for a sample .NET CORE MVC project and I am struggling with adding tests to a `ViewComponent` which includes `IOptions` and `IHostingEnvironment`. It's a simple view component that returns values from the *appsettings.json* file and this itself works without issue.

appsettings.json Snippet:

```
"Application": {"Name": "My App","Version": "1.0.0","Author": "John Doe", "Description": "Just a template!"}
```

ViewComponent:

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "Footer")]
public class FooterViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly IOptions<AppSettings.Application> _app;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public FooterViewComponent(IOptions<AppSettings.Application> app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _app = app;
        _env = env;
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        var vm = new FooterViewModel();
        {
            vm.AppName = _app.Value.Name;
            vm.AppVersion = _app.Value.Version;
            vm.AppEnvironment = _env.EnvironmentName;
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

I would like to test that the return type is a `ViewComponent` result and the View Model is not empty.

ViewComponent Test:

```
public class FooterViewComponentTest
{
    public class Should
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ReturnViewCompnentWithViewModel()
        {
            // Arrange
            var viewComp = new FooterViewComponent(??????????);

            // Act
            var result = viewComp ??????????;

            // Assert
            Assert.IsType<ViewComponentResult>(result);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm still working on this and will edit my snippets with my findings. Does anybody have any suggestions and should I be writing the tests in this format?

Comment: mock the dependencies and inject them into the subject under test, exercise the method under test by invoking it and the assert that the result is as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the well known Moq Framework you can write mock objects of the dependency abstractions and inject them in the constructor of the component like this:

```
public class FooterViewComponentTest
{
    public class Should
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ReturnViewCompnentWithViewModel()
        {
            // Arrange
            var appSettings = new AppSettings.Application();
            appSettings.AppName = "app";
            appSettings.Version = "1.0";
            var optionsMock = new Mock<IOptions<AppSettings.Application>>();
            optionsMock.Setup(o => o.Value).Returns(appSettings);

            var hostingMock = new Mock<IHostingEnvironment>();
            hostingMock.Setup(h => h.Environment).Returns("Test");

            var viewComp = new FooterViewComponent(optionsMock.Object, hostingMock.Object);

            // Act
            var result = viewComp.Invoke();

            // Assert
            Assert.IsType<ViewComponentResult>(result);

        }
    }
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the mocking framework.

Comment: Thanks Guys. Tests are now working. Changed the Assert action to:  Assert.IsType<ViewViewComponentResult>(result);